# Weak points/Ways to damage a Hunter/Weapon choice

Tags: halo-4

- **Weapon Weakness** - Specifically address weakness to Spartan, Covenant, and Promethean weapons in detail.  Include the area to target if appropriate.  I think a good measure would be how many hits on your recommended spot does it take with the indicated weapon.

  For example, I just recently noticed a fully charged plasma pistol burst will cause a splash of orange blood even with a direct hit protected by their shield, but I'm unsure how much "real" damage this does.
- **Sniping/Ranged Attack** -  Can they be sniped? Relative effectiveness of midrange/long range weapons excluding explosives/lasers.
- **Power Weapons** - Number of hits needed per power weapon.  Indicate weak area to target on front of hunter if appropriate.

Grenades are understood as a good option if available, so no need to discuss that.  Also, the back is a known vulnerability, but please explore additional points since that may not always be a reasonable option.

If difficulty impacts health, let us test this on Legendary.

Comment: Engaging a hunter and measuring its response to various weapons is a tall order...  perhaps at some point we'll get a custom mode for Spartan Ops (Reach had this for Firefight), but in the absence of that trying to test this has so far yielded frustration.

Comment: I may be forced to accept my own challenge.  Assuming Spartan Ops Legendary is the same difficulty as Campaign, I have an avenue to some of this information.

Comment: EP2 CH 4 - Pelican Down - There are two Hunters which drop at range.  Available Beam Rifle, UNSC Sniper, Battle Rifle/DMR (Loadout), Cov Carbine to test Sniping.  They basically don't move unless you get within physical proximity.

EP3CH5 = Hunting Trip - Avail Fuel Rod, Rockets, Spartan Laser, Plasma Stationary Guns

EP2CH3 - Hacksaw - Avail Saw and pretty much any other Spartan Weapon for testing

I'll get working on an answer myself if no one else jumps up in the next week or so.

Comment: Yeah, part of the problem is hitting them consistently, (they tend to hunker down once they've seen you, which makes hitting their weak spots harder) and having enough ammo to kill.  Legendary's going to make your job that much harder - I don't think you can carry enough DMR/BR ammo to take a hunter down on Legendary without resupply.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience playing Spartan Ops solo on legendary I can say the following:

**Spartan Laser**: It takes 2 shots to take down a Hunter. You may be able to kill them in one shot if you can hit them in their back portion (just below the armor), but I haven't tested this.

**Fuel Rod Cannon**: It takes 6/7 shots to take down a Hunter depending on where you place the shots. Shots landing directly on their shield seems to slightly reduce the damage dealt.

**Plasma Grenade**: It takes roughly 6 grenades to take down a Hunter. I imagine the Frag Grenade has a similar requirement.

**Rocket Launcher**: It takes 2 to 3 shots to take down a Hunter, again this depends on where you land the hits.

**Sniper Rifle**: In previous games it took 2 direct hits to take down a Hunter (those are hits that hit their 'orange' area. I imagine it is similar in Halo 4, although I haven't confirmed this.

**Shotgun**: It takes 7/8 shots to take down a Hunter. These shots 'must' hit their orange area. My tactic for this is usually as follows: practically hug the Hunter while it's facing you. When it does it's charge / slam attack, jump over it, quickly turn around and shoot him/it in it's back just below the armor. At this point you have to quickly be aware of their backwards slam strike. Again, jump over it or strafe to your left/right and shoot in their back again. Rinse and repeat.

*This tactic basically applies to any non power weapon. You have to keep them close to you so they can expose their non-armored areas. If you maintain a certain distance from the Hunters they'll constantly 'hunker down' making it very tedious to kill them. This tactic does require a bit of practice on the timing of your jumps and/or strafes.*

**Sticky Detonator**: It takes 4/5 shots to take down a Hunter: [This clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpTibP0wad4) greatly demonstrates how you should do this. Stick them on their heads, detonate. Rinse repeat.

---

One other, more general tactic ( any weapon ) is to use the Hologram armor ability: Allow your hologram to grab the Hunters attention and then quickly land a few shots in the back while it's facing your hologram. This tactic does take quite long though.

Comment: I'd add that the elite power sword works well too - two hits to the orange back area takes them out.

Comment: @Keith Do you use the sword lunge for that? Sounds dangerous, lunging takes longer than just doing a normal melee hit so it increases the chances of getting smacked in the face by their shield. Feel free however, to add it to the list.

Comment: I tried swording some on spartan ops last night.  If you hit them head on it temporarily stuns them.  Kind of a nice plus.  Didn't think to count the hits at the time, but I think 3-5 head on lunges in rapid succession did the trick.  Might be good to make 2 hunters into 1 at least.

Answer (score 0):

The saw does well if you shoot in burst at the rocket gun forged on the hunter. It takes a good min, so have some kind of cover around.